# Copy a word from the html file of a web page using shell script

Tags: scripts, grep, websites, html

I am trying to write a shell script which should crawl into a web page and fetch a particular character/phrase from its html and display it. Particular character means, for example if the html of the webpage contains a phrase, say `password:blah`, then I want to print the very next character/word to `password`, i.e., in short I want the script to print `blah`. How can I do this?

If more explanation needed, kindly ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: using wget/curl and grep could work on your example but what if the html contains `password:blah<br>!#foo` and I want to get `blah<br>!#foo` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a shell script. Probably the following compound command is what you need:

```
curl -s webpage | grep -Po 'password:\K\w+'
```

For example, the case of this page works:

```
curl -s http://askubuntu.com/questions/537416/copy-a-word-from-the-html-file-of-a-web-page-using-shell-script | grep -Po 'password:\K\w+'
```

Comment: Not sure that it works if the password is `blah<br>!#foo`.

Comment: @SylvainPineau Unlike you, I'm sure that it not works in this case :)) . But the OP was referred to a word.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Could you please explain me the use of `-Po` and `\K\w+`?

Comment: @AnanduMDas: `\K` only return the strings after `\K` (See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns). `w+` match one or more "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_", plus other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
wget -qO- http://website.com | grep -oP 'password:.*'
```

See [man wget](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/wget.1.html) for all options. `wget` can download the whole website.